# Response time from nodejs server with express on raspberry pi extremely slow

Tags: node.js, http, express, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

**TLDR;** http response extremely slow when on raspberry pi, super fast on local

I have a raspberry pi 3 with a nodejs server running express on my local network.

The server is always doing some work in the background and I made a rest api to check on the progress.

When the get is called the server sends me a html file with a script file attached to it, and the script calls another api to get the raw data and inject it into the html file. (I do this so I don't have to inject the data on the server)

Now here's the problem: When I run the server on my pc everything is fast. But on my raspberry the sending of the almost empty html + js + css files takes up to 10 seconds. I checked with the cpu and ram usages and it's always around 50% so that should not be an issue.

Does anybody have an idea what is causing that?

work.js

```
var db = require('./db.js');

var storeCollection;
var allowCollection;
var dbToClose;

module.exports.get = get;

function get(query, callback) {
    db.connect(function(database){
        storeCollection = database.collection(query+"store");
        allowCollection = database.collection(query+"allow");
        dbToClose = database;
        getOne(query, 1, callback);
    });

}
function getOne(query, page, callback) {
    jsdom.env(searchurl + query + pageparam + page, function (err, window) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        var $ = jquery(window);
        var resultlist = $("...");
        var count = 0;
        if(resultlist.length <= 0){
            dbToClose.close();
            callback("work");
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < resultlist.length; i++) {
            var item = new Object();

            //data parsing

            if (item.link) {
                item._id = new Buffer(item.link).toString('base64');
                db.addOneIfAllowed(storeCollection,allowCollection,item,function(){
                    if(++count == resultlist.length){
                        getOne(query, ++page, callback);
                    }
                });
            } else{
                dbToClose.close();
                callback("work");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

web.js

```
//rest api
...


//work
updateDatabase();
setInterval(updateDatabase, 60000 * 5);

function updateDatabase() {
    timer.start();
    db.connect(function (database) {
        var persist = database.collection("persist");
        persist.find({}).toArray(function (err, persisting) {
            database.close();
            persisting.forEach(function (q) {
                persistAll(q._id);
            });
        });
    });
}

function persistAll(q) {
    var workcount = 0;
    var time;
    function finish(name) {
        console.log("persisted "+name);
        workcount++;
        if (workcount == 6) {
            console.log("done persisting");
        }
    }
    time = Date.now();
    work.get(q, finish);
    otherwork.get(q,finish);
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's not really hard to take a more systematic approach to finding out what's slowing things down. For instance, are the HTTP requests faster when you disable the "background" task entirely? Or when you disable parts of it (say, the database writes)?

Comment: @robertklep it's a little bit faster without database calls, but it's not a big difference. I decided to make a second nodejs server which handles only the api calls and that is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're starving the IO bound tasks (the part that's responsible of sending the response back).

> The server is always doing some work in the background

What kind of work? care to share some code?

Check out [setImmediate](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args) or have a look at the excellent [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) library.

Comment: I'm basically grabbing all kinds of data from different websites and saving it in a database. Since I'm using http requests and database operations it should be mostly async, but I can try wrapping everything in an async call. Do you know a reason why there's **that** much of a difference on my pi than on my pc?

Comment: To be fair you didn't provide enough details to pinpoint the problem. Share some code.

Comment: Why do you use jsdom? are you scraping data?

Comment: yes, I am parsing data from the websites and wanted to use jquery